# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

How do is show that for $-1<x<1$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+x}$ converges uniformly.

For $x\geq0$ I can make a convergent Majorant series, choosing $M_n = 1/n^3$, but I can't seem to determine a convergent Majorant series for $-1<x<0$.

Comment: what about $\;\frac1{n^3-1}\;$ ...?

Comment: That was my initially guess, but the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-1}$ then has a singularity and diverges.

Comment: No, that series cannot have any singularity at all because it is a numerical *convergent* series, meaning: it is **a number** ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\forall n\geq 2$, $\max_{x\in (-1,1)} |f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n^3-1}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-1}$ converges, your series has [normal convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence) and thus converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$.

Now, let $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions that converges uniformly towards $g$ on a given interval $I$. Let $h$ be a well-defined function over $I$. Since $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly, we have:
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_\epsilon\in\mathbb{N};\forall n\in \mathbb{N},n\geq N_\epsilon, \forall x\in I, |g_n(x)-g(x)|\leq \epsilon
$$
Then:
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_\epsilon\in\mathbb{N};\forall n\in \mathbb{N},n\geq N_\epsilon, \forall x\in I, |(g_n(x)+h(x))-(g(x)+h(x))|\leq \epsilon
$$
So $(g_n + h)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $g+h$ over $I$.

Then, let $I=(-1,1)$, $g_n =\sum_{k=2}^n f_n$ be your series and $h=f_1$ be the missing part and you may conclude.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-1}$ has a singularity for $n=1$, so how do you argue that the series is convergent?

Comment: @RasmusSøgaardChristensen: $-1$ is not in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Applying Weierstrass. For every $r \in (-1,1)$ you can consider $A_r = (r,1)$. Now apply M-test using that $\forall x \in A_r$
$$
\frac{1}{n^3+x} \leq \frac{1}{n^3+r}
$$
And obviously
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+r} < \infty
$$
You can check it by comparation with $\sum_n 1/n^3$. So you prove uniform convergence in $A_r$. Now take limit $r\to -1$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n^3+r} > \frac{1}{n^3}$ for $r\in]-1,0[$, so I'm not sure how you argue that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+r}$ is convergent?.

Comment: Oh, sorry. By comparation by taking limit.

Comment: @RasmusSøgaardChristensen If $a_n$, $b_n$ are sequence such than $\lim_n a_n / b_n \in [0,\infty)$ and $\sum_n b_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_n a_n$ too. Obviusly, $\lim_n (n^3+r)/n^3 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could use a simple comparison test.  Since $|\frac 1{n^2}|>|\frac 1 {n^3-x}| for -1<x<1$, and since the sum of the reciprocal squares is uniformly convergent, then it follows that your original sum is also convergent.

Comment: So this holds for $n \geq 2$, which is okay, since I only need to look at the tail?